# Avoid Google Script trigger each time a sheet is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have 4 Google scripts in Google Sheets that run from a dropdown list (One,Two,Three,Four):

[image]

Each script gets triggered when the cell value (C2) in my "Admin" Tab changes.

I then ran a Script Trigger to activate this script:

[image]

I have tried to change the setting to On Edit and to on Change, but my problem persists;

**The script gets triggered each time any change is made to the entire sheet, whereas I only want the script triggered when Cell C2 in the "Admin" Tab is changed.**

I would value any feedback on the matter. @Tanaike

Regards,
Brendon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the script when the active sheet is the sheet of `Admin`.

For this, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the event object is used.

#### Modified script:

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Admin") return;
  
  var functions = {1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three, 4: Four};
  var value = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  functions[value]();
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the event object is NOT used.

```
function installedOnEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Admin") return;
  
  var functions = {1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three, 4: Four};
  var value = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  functions[value]();
}
```

### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getSheetName())

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike - my daily limit for triggers have been exceeded because of the problem you just solved. This means I will not be able to fully test it, but will give you feedback based on running the script manually in the meantime! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Rugbycology Analytics Thank you for replying. I could understand by your clear question. Thank you, too. At the pattern 2, you can test it by directly executing with the script editor.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike the fix worked perfectly - I just had to set the trigger to On Change. Thank you so much for the help!